# Set Default Value to a Combo box, when data is taken from a Store

Tags: combobox, dojo

In Dojo I want to set the first/top option  of may Store as the default/displaying option/text  of the combo box. I went through the documentation to found no help. if anyone have done that before please share your opinion.

Ps - I can't use ID or name of the option to set it. I want to display what ever the data item somes first in the store to display.

Thanks in advance.

and this is how my combo-box looks like

```
 var Selectbox = new dijit.form.ComboBox({
            id: "box1",
            disabled:true,
            uppercase:true,
            autoComplete:false,
            trim:true,
            value: "boxvalue",
            store:detailDataStore,
            style:"width:120px; color:black;"

        }).placeAt(topContentPane10.containerNode);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't a magic property to set the combobox default selection from a store, you'll have to set it manually.

Something like this:

```
box.set('value',store.data[0].value)
```

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Gkbpb/1/